# Delphi Excel COM-Addin

Tags: delphi, excel, com, add-in

I am writting an MS Excel COM-Addin in Delphi 2006.  I'm have Excel 2007 installed on my development machine.

I started the project as an ActiveX Library and then added an Automation object from the Delphi ActiveX project menu.

In my automation object I defined the IDTExtensibility2 interface as

```
IDTExtensibility2 = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{32E456FC-C710-43AA-9ACA-DDE8F132B91B}']
  function OnAddinsUpdate(var w_Custom: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function OnBeginShutDown(var w_Custom: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function OnConnection(const w_Application: IDispatch; w_ConnectMode: Integer;
                      const w_AddInInst: IDispatch; var w_Custom: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function OnDisconnection(w_DisconnectMode: Integer; var w_Custom: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
  function OnStartupComplete(var w_Custom: OleVariant): HResult; stdcall;
end;
```

and implemented the interface in a class that derived from TAutoObject.

In the initialization section of the unit I call

```
TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TPBSExcelAddin, Class_PBSExcelAddin, ciSingleInstance, tmApartment);
```

com object registers fine and shows up in Excel Addin options however it will in install in excel.  I just get the error "Not loaded. An error has occurred during the loading of the COM Addin"

Can anyone see a problem with my interface? or the way I am creating the com object? is there a way to debug this?

Thank you

Comment: I tried to do this some while back. It's hard to get it right. Eventually I discovered Add-in Express which I cannot recommend highly enough.

Comment: Thanks David. I have considered Add-in Express but I would rather do it from scratch for my own learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your declaration of `IDTExtensibility2` wrong.  It should be:

```
IDTExtensibility2 = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{B65AD801-ABAF-11D0-BB8B-00A0C90F2744}']
  procedure OnConnection(const Application: IDispatch; ConnectMode: ext_ConnectMode;
                         const AddInInst: IDispatch; var custom: PSafeArray); safecall;
  procedure OnDisconnection(RemoveMode: ext_DisconnectMode; var custom: PSafeArray); safecall;
  procedure OnAddInsUpdate(var custom: PSafeArray); safecall;
  procedure OnStartupComplete(var custom: PSafeArray); safecall;
  procedure OnBeginShutdown(var custom: PSafeArray); safecall;
end;
```

One thing that is crucial to remember is that methods in an interface must be declared in the correct order—you declared them in the wrong order. I also don't know where you got your GUID from.

I obtained this interface declaration by importing the type library for Microsoft Add-In Designer. I strongly recommend that you do the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I did manage to figure it out on my own, it took a bit of searching the internet until I found that you can import the type library rather than having to declare it yourself.  This is really the first time to write a COM Addin so I didn't know about type library importing.  I've worked out how to add buttons and events which are showing up on the Addin tab as expected.

Comment: Good to hear your add-in is up and running. Now I wish you good luck with writing code to interact with the ribbon! That's fun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to debug this:

1. Close Excel
2. Open your project options (Ctrl+Shift+F11)
3. Go to the Linker tab
4. Check *Include TD32 debug info* and *Include remote debugging symbols*. (Maybe only the first is needed, but better safe than sorry)
5. Go to Run Parameters (Run menu, Parameters...)
6. Change the Host Application to Excel
7. Rebuild and run, as soon as your addin is loaded you can start debugging.

When you never get into debugging, which means the problem is probably not in your initialization code, then maybe there is a problem with loading the necessary packages or, your addin does not implement the _IDExtensibility interface the right way.

Comment: Thanks The_Fox that is very helpfull.  But what is the correct way to define the IDTExtensibility interface in Delphi? I'm not sure of what types to use for the Custom and Application parameters.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I remember some problems when trying to debug (not able to set breakpoints) a dll/bpl by setting a host application which I think I solved with Step 4. It doesn't hurt to set those properties anyway.

Comment: You only need to set those properties when you are using a debugger that relies on TD32 symbols.

Comment: I think the problem is with how to interface is declared.  Could someone please give me the correct interface definion for Delphi?